# "IN" keyword sql file path

Tags: sql-server

While moving an app from access to sql server I have come across a keyword that is causing errors.  The keyword within the query is "IN".  INSERT INTO Table IN 'file path of sql server database'.  Does sql server allow you to insert data using the file path within the query? I have been researching this for a few days and have come up with nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Give us 1 full insert statment please just as an example

Answer (score 2):

The `IN` keyword in Microsoft Access in this syntax allows you to specify another database file where the table is. This is equivalent to being in another database in Sql Server.

It looks like you are taking multiple Access database files and importing them into multiple Sql Server databases. Let's say you have an Access database called One.MDB and it gets some data from a table in Access database Two.MDB, and you have imported into Sql Server into databases `One` and `Two`. So you need to get the data from the other database. Sql Server uses a syntax of `Database.Schema.Table` (the schema by default is the database owner schema, or dbo).

So this in Microsoft Access:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable IN 'Two.MDB' ...
```

translates to this in Sql Server:

```
INSERT INTO Two.dbo.MyTable ...
```

That's assuming you are still using separate databases. If you've put it all in the same database, you just need to reference the table directly:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ...
```

Comment: This is the full insert statement.     INSERT INTO AddressBook IN 'C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\WCCSNEW.mdf' SELECT [Record_ID], [CustCode], [Sequence], [Last], [First], [Name2], [Address1], [City], [State], [Zip], [Country], [Phone], [Phone2], [Fax], [TypeOfTIN], [TIN], [Salutation], [Email], [RoutingNum], [OkToDelete], [InUse], [UserID] FROM AddressBook;           What I am doing is building a new database WCCSNEW and then attempting to load the data from the original database then delete the original.  It is an update process.

Comment: Both databases are sql server.  No mdbs' involved. This insert statement is part of the update process and was used for the old mdb file.

Comment: This is the message I received:  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'

Comment: If I am reading your comment correctly Chris, I should drop the keyword "IN"?

Comment: This is the result of dropping the "IN" keyword:  Incorrect syntax near 'C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\WCCSNEW.mdf'. on INSERT INTO AddressBook 'C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\WCCSNEW.mdf' SELECT [Record_ID], [CustCode], [Sequence], [Last], [First], [Name2], [Address1], [City], [State], [Zip], [Country], [Phone], [Phone2], [Fax], [TypeOfTIN], [TIN], [Salutation], [Email], [RoutingNum], [OkToDelete], [InUse], [UserID] FROM AddressBook;

Comment: Yes - your new database is called WCCSNEW and you are accessing it via Sql Server now from another database? Then you drop the 'IN' keyword and the file path and just use the database directly: INSERT INTO WCCSNEW.dbo.AddressBook

Comment: Actually, if you just want to insert from one table to another and they have the same structure you can just do: INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM Table1

Comment: I am not connected to WCCSNEW.mdf. I am connected to WCCS.mdf. WCCS.mdf will be deleted after the data is inserted and WCCSNEW will be renamed WCCS. I built WCCSNEW from code while connected to WCCS. Now that it's built the next step is moving the data from the connected WCCS.mdf to WCCSNEW.mdf. Hope that helps to clarify.

Comment: Are you doing this from Sql Server or from Access?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your description it should just be (assuming you have all the right permissions to access the new database): INSERT INTO WCCSNEW.dbo.AddressBook SELECT [Record_ID], [CustCode], [Sequence], [Last], [First], [Name2], [Address1], [City], [State], [Zip], [Country], [Phone], [Phone2], [Fax], [TypeOfTIN], [TIN], [Salutation], [Email], [RoutingNum], [OkToDelete], [InUse], [UserID] FROM AddressBook;

Comment: I don't know how I can do what you suggested if I am not connected to wccsnew.  This is all being done from code in my app which is connected to a different database (wccs.mdf) at the time this is all happening. I am essentially trying to pass data to an external database (wccsnew) from wccs.mdf. I'll try and come up with another option.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: I am going to try the OPENDATASOURCE function. I will post the outcome afterwards in case anyone comes across this issue.